# Proof of this function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have this question in my text book. I am confused how to prove it.

> Show that:
>   $$\sqrt{x+\Delta x} = \sqrt{x} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\Delta x$$

Comment: I do not believe that is a valid equality. (That is, I think that isn't a correct equation.)  Also, please make sure that I didn't make an error when transcribing your image to use $\LaTeX$ formatting.

Comment: If $x=\Delta x=1$ then left side is equal to $\sqrt{2}$ but right side is equal to  $\frac{3}{2}$ so the equality is false.

Comment: I think the book is talking about approximation of values of well behaved functions via their differential...but this is just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

I think they mean
$$\sqrt{x+\Delta x} \approx \sqrt{x} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\Delta x$$
where $\approx$ means "approximately equal to".

This is one way to do it:

$\begin{align}
\sqrt{x+\Delta x} - \sqrt{x}
&=(\sqrt{x+\Delta x} - \sqrt{x})\frac{\sqrt{x+\Delta x} + \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+\Delta x} + \sqrt{x}}\\
&=\frac{(\sqrt{x+\Delta x} - \sqrt{x})(\sqrt{x+\Delta x} + \sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x+\Delta x} + \sqrt{x}}\\
&=\frac{(x+\Delta x) - x}{\sqrt{x+\Delta x} + \sqrt{x}}\\
&=\frac{\Delta x}{\sqrt{x+\Delta x} + \sqrt{x}}\\
&\approx\frac{\Delta x}{2\sqrt{x}}\\
\end{align}
$

since
$\sqrt{x+\Delta x}
\approx \sqrt{x}
$
as 
$\Delta x \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you have to show that the rhs is an approximation of the lhs when $\Delta x$ is small compared to $x$.

While I was typing, marty cohne's answer came and this is, for sure, one good way.

I propose another one : extract $\sqrt{x}$ from the radical on the lhs. You then obtain

$$ \sqrt{x} \sqrt{1+\frac{\Delta x}{x}}$$

I am sure you know that when $y$ is small $(1+y)^n$ is pretty well approximated by $(1 + n y)$. Replace $y$ by $\Delta x$ and $n$ by $\frac{1}{2}$. You then have

$$ \sqrt{x} \left( 1+ \frac{\Delta x}{2x} \right ) $$

Now expand and simplify.

Comment: @alex.jordan. I totally agree and I am sorry for that. Have a look to my profile. I am almost totally blind and everything (beside plain ASCII) is hard to me since I do not see what I type. When my answers contain a very little amount of LaTeX, it just reveals that my wife made a cut and paste from another answer.

Comment: Immense respect to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an illustration of the significance of the relationship.

$\sqrt {x+\Delta x} \approx \sqrt x + \Delta x \frac {d(\sqrt x)} {dx} = \sqrt x + \Delta x \frac 1 {2 \sqrt x}$.

Basically, letting $f(x) = \sqrt x$, the result says $f(x+\Delta x) \approx f(x) + \Delta x f'$. The smaller $\Delta x$ is, the closer the approximation. In the LHS, we are adding $\Delta x$ before applying the function. On the RHS we start at $x$ and get the rate of increase of the function and multiply that by how far away $\Delta x$ is. The rate may change between $[x, x+ \Delta x]$ and we are not taking those changes into consideration, hence it is an approximation.